# ¿Se puede revertir en git un push de otro usuario?

Tags: git, github, push

El tema es el siguiente, quiero revertir el Push de otros usuarios cuando quiera, ejemplo:

- UsrA y UsrB trabajan en un repositorio
- UsrB hace un Push
- UsrA lo quiere revertir completamente para que quede como si UsrB nunca hizo ese Push.

¿Como se podria hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

Hace poco me pasó esto.

Una forma de lograrlo es:

- Usuario A descarga los cambios de B
- Usuario A se entera de la desgracia y decide ejecutar un `git reset` hasta el último commit estable
- Usuario A sube los cambios al repositorio remoto usando `git push origin master --force`

Este último comando considera `origin` como alias del repositorio remoto, y `master` como el nombre de la rama sobre la que estás trabajando. Puede cambiar según la configuración de tu proyecto.